# Javascript match function for special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters, match

I am working on this code and using "match" function to detect strength of password. how can I detect if string has special characters in it?

```
if(password.match(/[a-z]+/)) score++;
if(password.match(/[A-Z]+/)) score++;
if(password.match(/[0-9]+/)) score++;
```

Comment: Anything which is not a letter or number would be a special character match.

Answer (score 12):

If you mean !@#$% and ë as special character you can use:

```
/[^a-zA-Z ]+/
```

The `^` means if it is not something like a-z or A-Z or a space.

And if you mean only things like !@$&$ use:

```
/\W+/
```

`\w` matches word characters, `\W` matching not word characters.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to whitelist them individually, like so:

```
if(password.match(/[`~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\-=_+\\\[\]{}/\?,\.\<\> ...
```

and so on. Note that you'll have to escape regex control characters with a `\`.

While less elegant than `/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/`, this will avoid internationalization issues (e.g., will not automatically whitelist Far Eastern Language characters such as Chinese or Japanese).

Answer (score 2):

you can always negate the character class:

```
if(password.match(/[^a-z\d]+/i)) {
    // password contains characters that are *not*
    // a-z, A-Z or 0-9
}
```

However, I'd suggest using a ready-made script. With the code above, you could just type a bunch of spaces, and get a better score.

Answer (score 1):

Just do what you did above, but create a group for `!@#$%^&*()` etc.  Just be sure to escape characters that have meaning in regex, like `^` and `(` etc....

EDIT -- [I just found this which lists characters that have meaning in regex](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(password.match(/[^\w\s]/)) score++;
```

This will match anything that is not alphanumeric or blank space. If whitespaces should match too, just use `/[^\w]/`.

Answer (score 1):

As it look from your regex, you are calling everything except for alphanumeric a special character. If that is the case, simply do.

```
if(password.match(/[\W]/)) {
    // Contains special character.
}
```

Anyhow how why don't you combine those three regex into one.

```
if(password.match(/[\w]+/gi)) {
    // Do your stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/
This will accept only special characters and will not accept a to z & A to Z 0 to 9 digits

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).