# Vue.js filrter not works with special character

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a filter witch looks inside a `items: {}` array, this array have 26 objects inside. The object **24** have an alias with special character `ñ`. The filter not works on this object and the next ones until the end of the items array.

```
items: {
    [...]
    23: {
      alias: "Correcto",
      id: 11
    },
    24: {
      alias: "Tamaño",
      id: 12
    }
    25: {
      alias: "silla",
      id: 13
    }
};
```

This is the code of my filter as a `computed:` porperty

```
computed: {
      filteredItems() {
          if (this.items) {
              return this.items.filter((item) => {
                  if (!this.search) return '';
                  return item.alias.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase().trim());
              });
          }
      }
  },
```

How can i make the filter works with any type of characters?

Comment: possible [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230595/javascript-match-function-for-special-characters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js filter not works with big array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406868/vue-js-filter-not-works-with-big-array)

Comment: @i-- this is the first issue i post because i suspect about the special characters. In the comment of the answer i link the other answer...

Comment: @RicardoAlbear - the questions are identical with different title. You just need to generalize the question into one and say, here is the problem, here is what I tried, what am I doing wrong? Probably should not attempt to give a possible answer in your question. Just delete one of them and update your title/description.

Comment: @i-- The questions are not identical, i reuse the code. Stackoverflow say "► clarify meaning without changing it ► correct minor mistakes" when i edit so i make a new question. In the first attempt i think was related to the special characters not to the array length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the correct encoding. [This](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) library offers a plugin to support a wide range of varying language formats.

[Unicode](http://www.utf8-chartable.de) would give you a consistent and widely supported base.

Comment: Finally looks like the problem is other, i post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406868/vue-js-filter-not-works-with-big-array)