# Vue.js computed property does not works with big array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a computed property witch looks inside a `items: {}` array, this array have 26 objects inside. The property only "read" the first 23 objects, the 24 and the next ones looks out of the filter range.

Before this conclusion i think the problem is because the **24** object have an special character but i revert the array order and the special character was filter correctly.

```
items: [
    {...},
    23: {
      alias: "Correcto",
      id: 11
    },
    24: {
      alias: "Tamaño",
      id: 12
    }
    25: {
      alias: "silla",
      id: 13
    ]
};
```

This is the code of my filter as a `computed:` porperty

```
computed: {
      filteredItems() {
          if (this.items) {
              return this.items.filter((item) => {
                  if (!this.search) return '';
                  return item.alias.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase().trim());
              });
          }
      }
  },
```

How can i make the filter works with big arrays?

Comment: `{}` is not an array, it is an object.

Comment: @RicardoAlbear, year you must have mistyped the `{}` in place of `[]`, if you code works at all. Question: how did you check that it stops reading after a certain point?

Comment: Yep, is `[]` i fast type a sample because i can´t copy the real data. I check it using the filter and with the vue-debug inspector. Also i change the order of the array and the filter always skip the last objects. First i think it was a special characters issue but looks like a size problem.

Comment: I am confused as to how you can inspect your filter because it filters items by whatever is in your `search` var and should be empty if `search = ''`.

Comment: I check it manually, typing in the search filter the `alias` value, all works except the object **24** and nexts. I use the vue-debug inspector to verify the order of the objects in the array. The filter was working great long ago but today i find this issue with long arrays. Maybe the `filter` have some limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Array's filter method does not has a limitation, the problem here it's the `.match()` method which check by `regex`, replace it with `.includes()` which search if the string passed as parameter occours in the desired string.

[.includes() Docs MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Little example emulating "large" data

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  computed: {
    filteredItems () {
      return this.items.filter(i => i.alias.toLowerCase().includes(this.filterText.toLowerCase()))
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      filterText: '',
      items: [
        {
          alias: "it\'s working",
          id: 1
        },
        {
          alias: "lool",
          id: 2
        },
        {
          alias: "vue is awesome",
          id: 3
        },
        {
          alias: "another text",
          id: 4
        },
        {
          alias: "some value",
          id: 5
        },
        {
          alias: "teest",
          id: 6
        },
        {
          alias: "bar",
          id: 7
        },
        {
          alias: "foo",
          id: 8
        },
        {
          alias: "silla",
          id: 9
        },
        {
          alias: "Corrécto",
          id: 10
        },
        {
          alias: "Tamaño",
          id: 11
        },
        {
          alias: "ñoo",
          id: 12
        },
    {
      alias: "silla",
      id: 9
    },
    {
      alias: "Corrécto",
      id: 10
    },
    {
      alias: "Tamaño",
      id: 11
    },
    {
      alias: "ñoo",
      id: 12
    },
    {
      alias: "silla",
      id: 9
    },
    {
      alias: "Corrécto",
      id: 10
    },
    {
      alias: "Tamaño",
      id: 11
    },
    {
      alias: "ñoo",
      id: 12
    },
    {
      alias: "silla",
      id: 9
    },
    {
      alias: "Corrécto",
      id: 10
    },
    {
      alias: "Tamaño",
      id: 11
    },
    {
      alias: "ñoo",
      id: 12
    },
    {
      alias: "silla",
      id: 9
    },
    {
      alias: "Corrécto",
      id: 10
    },
    {
      alias: "Tamaño",
      id: 11
    },
    {
      alias: "ñoo",
      id: 12
    },
    {
      alias: "silla",
      id: 9
    },
    {
      alias: "Corrécto",
      id: 10
    },
    {
      alias: "Tamaño",
      id: 11
    },
    {
      alias: "ñoo",
      id: 12
    }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>


<div id="example">
  
  <input type="text" v-model="filterText" />
  
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in filteredItems">{{ item.alias }}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you can't get a match when searching strings with characters outside of `a-Z` range. A basic solution could be to use js [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) function that converts characters to UTF-16 codes. Below is a basic example:

```
function encodeString(str) {
    return str.split('').map(letter => letter.charCodeAt(0)).join('~'); // ~ is to split chars and not to let one mix with other acidentally
}
```

so your code might actually look something like this:

```
...

computed: {
    filteredItems() {
        if (this.items) {
            return this.items.filter(item => {
                if (!this.search) return false;
                return this.isMatching(item.alias, this.search);
            });
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    ...
    encodeString(str) {
        return str.split('').map(letter => letter.charCodeAt(0)).join('~');
    },
    isMatching(haystack, keyword) {
        haystack = haystack.toLowerCase().trim();
        keyword = keyword.toLowerCase().trim();
        return this.encodeString(haystack).match(this.encodeString(keyword));
    },
    ...
}

...
```